# Link to div and $_GET

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

First - sorry for weird title, I just don't know how to call second part of the link in English.

But, I would like to have link like this www.something.com/?newsid=14#anchor1, when I click on link like this, it just moves me to the linked div called anchor1, but there is not content which should be under "newsid" 14.
How should the link looks like?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post some code here. Question is not clear.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC well OK, I just need to edit `<a href="linktosomewhere?newsid=14#anchor1">link here</a>` to work... this version just moves me to anchor1, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You can pass newsid in the link and get via $my_link = $_GET['newsid']. When you click on the link it will go to the new page there you can load the news for editing/viewing with the news which may comes from the DB.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC i know it should work, but it just doesn't.. newsid is not set to 14 after i click on that link...

Comment: print_r($_GET); on the second page. And see you get any values.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC well it should be scrolling web, only one page, that's why I must have that div id there..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104732/discussion-between-krishnadas-pc-and-h-sturma).